# Writing text to XML is taking long time --Java

Tags: java, xml

I have some 3000 elements in arraylist.Need to write these 3000 elements to xml.
The execution is taking too much time like 20 minutes in eclipse.
Is there any efficient way to do this?
OR any modifications to my code?

The elements in arraylist are supposed to grow in future...

MY code snippet..

```
---------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
for(int i=0;i<candidates.size();i++)//Candidates is my arraylist
            {
                String text=candidates.get(i);
                //System.out.println(text);
                text=text+"\n";
                file= new File("./test.xml");
                WriteToXML wr= new WriteToXML(file,"fullname",text);

            }
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
//WritetoXML class constructor
public WriteToXML(File xml,String tag,String data)
{
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(xml)));
        Element element =  doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList node1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        Element fn= (Element) node1.item(0);
        Text text = doc.createTextNode(data);
        fn.appendChild(text);
        printtoXML(doc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
}
public static final void printtoXML(Document xml) throws Exception {
    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw); 
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xml);
    tf.transform(source, result);
    String xmlString = sw.toString();
    File file= new File(xml);
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file,false);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(xmlString);
    bw.flush();
    bw.close(); 
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Comment: Your code is so slow because you always instantiate many objects per method call (File, FileWriter, .... ) to write in the xml file. I guess it'S much faster if you write once in the file and not 3000 times, because then you have to open it once (also close and write) and not 3000 times.

Comment: Do you suggest any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the for loop inside the WriteToXML().

Main function:

```
file= new File("./test.xml");
WriteToXML wr= new WriteToXML(file,"fullname",candidates)
```

Inside WriteToXML

```
public WriteToXML(File xml,String tag,List candidates )
{
    try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(xml)));
    Element element =  doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList node1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    Element fn= (Element) node1.item(0);
    for (int i=0;i<candidates.size();i++) { 
        Text text = doc.createTextNode(candidates.get(i)+"\n");
        fn.appendChild(text);
    }
    printtoXML(doc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This way you are not re-parsing the XML all the time and write it only once.

I've tried to do minimal changes. I would not recommend doing this in the constructor - unless there is a good reason to do so.

Comment: Modified my code accordingly.Execution time is less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are doing this for each of your 3000 elements:

1. Open the file
2. Parse the document in there
3. add an element to the dom structure
4. flush the file to disk and close it

Way faster would be to do steps 1, 2 and 4 only once (1 & 2 before the loop; 4 after the loop) and just do step 3 for every element in your list (in the loop).
Just write a new method which takes your `tag` variable and a `Document` instance and add the tag to the document.

What is really expensive here is the multiple conversion of Object structures to XML and back. This has a huge overhead.
File IO is also giving a lot of overhead, but even this should be small compared to the multiple creation and parsing of DOM structures.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SAX` instead of `DOM`. `SAX` is more efficient than `DOM`

Answer (score 1):

as @Masud suggests, Use SAX there is no other way. There is a great example about this [Generating XML from an Arbitrary Data Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT5.html)

Comment: This recommendation is misleading. As the task here is to write a XML structure from Objects which are already in memory (int that candidates List), DOM is perfectly fine for this. SAX may be great for extracting data and reducing memory consumption (which is not needed in this case), but it is not an answer to every XML performance question.

Comment: I suggest you should record the time in duration for each task creating dom document, parshing and writing to file. This will give you an idea which one takes long. And another thing you can pass StreamResult(File f) directly to transformer, this will reduce a step in your execution.